# Django: Best practices for using Model data in clientside javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I'm new to working with django and I am trying to send information to my clientside javascript. I have a list of FooBarModels that I want to use with my clientside Javascript. Currently, I'm using the django template to generate an array of dictionaries that holds the information I'll use with the Javascript.

This feels like a hacky solution, is there a better way to achieve this?

#### models.py

```py
class FooBarModel(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def desc(self):
        # logic here

    @property
    def display_name(self):
        # logic here
```

#### template.html

```html
<script>
var $fb_list = [
    {% for fb in foobar_list %}
    { "name": {{fb.display_name}}, "desc": {{fb.display_name}} },
    {% endfor %}
]

// a bunch of code that uses the $fb_list
</script>
```

What's the best practice for handling this type of situation? Should I be sending a package of JSON to the clientside and parsing it?

Answer (score 0):

This is called `Serialization`, Which means converting a django `django.db.Model` to `JSON`, the inverse of this is called `Deserialization` which means converting the `JSON` to a native object, this time -if it's a valid object-.

Django [supports](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/) it natively, And [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) extends this support.

Here's an example with django itself.

```
from django.core import serializers

data = serializers.serialize("json", SomeModel.objects.all()) # xml is supported too
print(data) # prints model as JSON
```

or

```
JSONSerializer = serializers.get_serializer("json")
json_serializer = JSONSerializer()
json_serializer.serialize(queryset)
data = json_serializer.getvalue()
print(data)
```

It needs a queryset EVEN if you are serializing a single object.